# Move Customers, Products and orders to new site

Tags: magento2, database, migration

I have just finished setting up a new site and I need to move the customers, products and orders/invoices to it from an existing Magento site.

Both are v2.3.5, I don't want to just transfer the complete database whats the best way of migrating them?

From what I have read the main issue is going to be with customer passwords